# Oracle_Scheduling_Job_ Can't set max_run_duration directly in DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB

Tags: oracle, job-scheduling

Today I need to create a Job, and kill it when it exceeds a given time when running.

I searched and found that I need to set attribute `max_run_duration` for that intention.

And my question is simple: Why I can't set that attribute directly when create job? Why I have to create job first then set that attribute later, or may I do something wrong?

Could someone explain this logic to me?

Maybe there are some `addition attributes` that is added in newer version of Oracle that Oracle staff feel it's bad to change the `create_funtion` and then add a `set_attribute` function for those new attributes?

**1**.The error script: (`ORA-06550: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CREATE_JOB'`)

```
BEGIN
 DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
  job_name           =>  'my_job_name',
  job_type           =>  'STORED_PROCEDURE',
  job_action         =>  'schema_name.procedure_name',
  start_date         =>   '24-OCT-16 08.00.00 PM',
  repeat_interval    =>  'FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=20;', 
  max_run_duration   =>  INTERVAL '4' HOUR,
  auto_drop          =>   FALSE,
  comments           =>  'my comment here');
END;
/
```

**2**.The ok script:

```
BEGIN
 DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
  job_name           =>  'my_job_name',
  job_type           =>  'STORED_PROCEDURE',
  job_action         =>  'schema_name.procedure_name',
  start_date         =>   '24-OCT-16 08.00.00 PM',
  repeat_interval    =>  'FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=20;', 
  --   max_run_duration   =>  INTERVAL '4' HOUR,
  auto_drop          =>   FALSE,
  comments           =>  'my comment here');

  DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE( 
  name => 'my_job_name', 
  attribute => 'max_run_duration', 
  value => INTERVAL '4' HOUR
  );
END;
/
```

Answer (score 3):

Check documentation, [CREATE_JOB Procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72300)

CREATE_JOB procedure is overloaded but none of the 6 procedure accepts parameter `max_run_duration`. You have to set this by `DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE` as intended.

Maybe you could use the [CREATE_JOBS Procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72304):

```
DECLARE
   jobs SYS.JOB_ARRAY;
   job SYS.JOB;
BEGIN
   job := SYS.JOB('my_job_name', 
      job_type =>  'STORED_PROCEDURE',
      ...);
   jobs := jobs(job);
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOBS(jobs)
END;
```

However, I did not manage it to create a job.